# drag and drop values from one div to another div and mysql queries after dropping

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drag-and-drop

this would be my first time for a drag and drop functionality. i have to make timetable application for a college which would require dragging from a list of teacher responsibilities  on the left side containing all the required values and dropping into a timetable slot on the right side, then popping up a dialog box for asking room number and then performing various checks at php and mysql level and then finally inserting into database. Also, without mentioning this has to be an ajax solution.

I really want this to be a pure javascript solution and not some frameworks like jquery, prototype etc as i have a race against time and i haven't ever used any frameworks before so i cant dish out time to learn one of these now. But if u guys cant help me with pure javascript, i'l have to use one of the above mentioned frameworks.

Please help as soon as possible. Also, do ask if u want some more clarification as to what exactly i want to achieve.

Comment: using a framework will definitely save you some time, even if you have to learn how to use it! See http://jqueryui.com/droppable/, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Option is : In core javascript you can use using HTML5 drag drop feature but it has problems specially in safari browser.

Second Option is : http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Put following code I'll tell you how to call ajax. I am still here to help you till you get expected output

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
    #left, #right { border:1px solid #000000;min-height:100px;min-width:100px;list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
    #left li, #right li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#left, #right" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            receive: function(event,ui){
                 console.log("old ui id = "+ui.sender.attr("id")+" new ul id = "+this.id+" li id "+$(ui.item).attr("id"));                   
                 if(ui.sender.attr("id") != this.id)
                 {  
                    //Your ajax call will come here


                            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "logic.php", 
         // Write you //php mysql logic here you'll get all your data in logic.php file 
                  data: { left: ui.sender.attr("id"), right: this.id , responsibility:$(ui.item).attr("id") }
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                            });
                 }
             }

        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="left" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2"  class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li id="3"  class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li id="4"  class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li id="5"  class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="right" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="6" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li id="7"  class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li id="8"  class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li id="9"  class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li id="10"  class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for ur willingness to help me till the end. Now, the code that you gave adds to the other list. i have a timetable application wherein i need to drag the items from a list on the left containing values to a timetable on the right which will have slots with x,y(day,monday) coordinates and i want to drop them in one or more of these slots which should then through ajax call a php file which will do appropriate checks and enter into db. if u stil want me to be more specific please let me know.And i still think jquery and the likes will take more time for me to understand

Comment: @Nikhil : See my latest code also. and You don't need to understand anything now. The main jquery work is I have completed you just need to put server side code (php) and mysql in that php file. data: { left: ui.sender.attr("id"), right: this.id , responsibility:$(ui.item).attr("id") ,new_parameter:'value',new_param2:'value' } You will get this at server side using $_POST. Also, it would be better if you give me link. If still you don't want to use jquery. Use html5 drag drop.

Comment: anup: i still havent understood how jquery is working here, and how will i store data in the left side list to be dragged to the right side empty slots and run ajax there

Comment: @Nikhil : Get latest edited code. If it is possible then send me link so I can help you more. AND if it is possible post your server side code as well. more info in logic.php file will you need to put your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20807/discussion-between-nikhil-verma-and-anup)

Comment: what is your email address?